# Counting the number of unique values by group

Tags: sql, oracle

Please tell me how you can count the number of unique "inn" values for each group where "publid", "clusterid", "issuedate", "operdate" are the same, as shown in the example.

Example

```
|*inn*|*publid*|*clusterid*|*issuedate*|*operdate*|
|-----|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|
| 333 |   1    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
| 222 |   1    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
| 333 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
| 222 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
| 111 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
|-----|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|
```

Result

```
|*inn*|*publid*|*clusterid*|*issuedate*|*operdate*|*count*|
|-----|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|-------|
| 333 |   1    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |   2   |
| 222 |   1    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |   2   |
| 333 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |   3   |
| 222 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |   3   |
| 111 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |   3   |
|-----|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|-------|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking for unique values i would do as follows

```
SELECT * 
       ,COUNT(distinct "inn") OVER (PARTITION BY "publid", "clusterid", "issuedate", "operdate") AS "count" 
  FROM TABLE
```

Comment: If you mix `*` with other columns/expressions then you have to prefix it; so would need e.g. `SELECT t.*, ... FROM SOME_TABLE t`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function:

```
SELECT *, 
COUNT("inn") OVER (PARTITION BY "publid", "clusterid", "issuedate", "operdate") AS "count" 
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: If you mix `*` with other columns/expressions then you have to prefix it; so would need e.g. `SELECT t.*, ... FROM SOME_TABLE t`. This will also count all values, even if repeated; you need `distinct` to avoid that, as George shows.